# "No connection could be made" to GitHub

Tags: ruby, github-api

I am trying to get this run to my test organization created on github.com, but got this error. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
C:\Workspace\Ruby>set GITHUB_TOKEN=xxx

C:\Workspace\Ruby>set GITHUB_API_ENDPOINT=http://api.github.com

C:\Workspace\Ruby>ruby team_audit.rb HudsonsBay
C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "api.github.com" port 80 (Faraday::Conn
ectionFailed)
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:75:in `timeout'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1133:in `get'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http
.rb:80:in `perform_request'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http
.rb:40:in `block in call'
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-
C:\Workspace\Ruby>
```

Comment: Try calling `https://api.github.com` instead of `http://` (SSL).

Comment: I hope you didn't post a real token. Also... are you sure your connection works? Are you able to perform HTTP calls from Ruby?

Comment: The problem is I am new to Ruby, just want to get a report working:https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/api/ruby/team_audit.rb#L63-L70. I tried SSL, error too. How can I verify if I can do http calls from Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make the same request and got the same error.

after changing the URL from `http://api.github.com` into `https://api.github.com` it working.

Comment: I got this error using https. C:\Workspace\Ruby>ruby team_audit.rb HudsonsBay
C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 stat
e=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (Faraday::SSLError)
        from C:/Tools/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. C:\Workspace\Ruby>ruby team_audit.rb HudsonsBay
Output written to HudsonsBay-2015-10-12/